# jQuery On Screen Keyboard On Second Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, on-screen-keyboard

I have a little problem on using Mottie's jQuery OSK(On Screen Keyboard) on dialog boxes. You might want to check this **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsmBe/1/)** to make it simpler.

When selecting the second input field on a jQuery dialog, it always jumps on the first input field.

Here are the codes I used:

HTML:

```
<div id='dialog' title='This is a title' style='display: none'>
<h3>I just want to say something</h3>
<label>Say something: </label><br />
<input type='text' id='SaySomething' /><br /><br />

<label>Enter another text: </label><br />
<input type='text' id='SaySomething2' /><br /><br /></div><button>Click me</button><br /><label>Say something: </label><br /><input type='text' id='SaySomethingOutside' /><br /><label>Enter another text: </label><br /><input type='text' id='SaySomethingOutside2' /><br />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
}).button();
$("input").keyboard();
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons : {
        OK: function(){
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `usePreview: false` as an parameter in the keyboard

See this edited [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsmBe/2/)

Comment: Do accept the answer if that helps you to solve your question.

Comment: Thanks! That actually helped. Another question, why is it always focusing on the first input field? Try this one, while focused on the second input field, click anywhere on the jQueryUI Dialog and it will focus back on first input field.